# Vim: good way to setup makeprg=xcodebuild?

Tags: vim, command-line, xcodebuild

What is the best way to set `makeprg=xcodebuild` in vim?

I'm using filetype line in files to indicate that the file is objective-c (as opposed to matlab or cpp) by setting up the first line of my file to:

```
/* vim: set filetype=objc : */
```

and having this in vimrc:

```
set modelines=1
```

I would probably want to use `:mak` to run this command in the current directory:

```
xcodebuild -activetarget -activeconfiguration
```

I usually end up setting manually `xcodebuild` as `makeprg` so that I can do `:mak` to compile.

I'm always in the project root directory where I have `.xcodeproj` files so I don't have to worry about searching for project files.

What's the best way to setup `makeprg`? `Ftplugin`? `Compiler` plugin?

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say `ftplugin`, it's very easy. Write this in `.vim/ftplugin/objc.vim`:

```
set makeprg=xcodebuild\ -activetarget\ -activeconfiguration
```

Also, Vim's filetype detector will consider your .m file to be Objective-C if it notices `#include`, `#import`, or `/*` in the first ten lines. You can write an `ftdetect` plugin to change the default: `.vim/ftdetect/objc.vim`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.m set filetype=objc
```

Comment: +1, I did not have `:filetype plugin on` so I guess it wasn't loading filetype plugins, I've added it and it's working now

Answer (score 1):

You could put something like the following into your .vimrc:

```
if len(glob( getcwd() . '/*.xcodeproj' )) > 0
    let &makeprg = 'xcodebuild'
endif
```

So when you start vim and there is a *.xcodeproj in the current directory, it sets the makeprg to xcodebuild.

Comment: This won't work if he edit files from different directories, with different filetypes, etc.
I would instead use a solution like local_vimrc (/project.vim) to detect where is the file currently edited, and whether its filetype is objc to apply the correct :setlocal (and not :set!).